# Migrate from iOS 4 to iOS 5 .

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios4, ios5

I have an application developed in iOS 4.3 and XCode 4.

What are the steps that I have to follow to migrate it to iOS 5?
Do I have to upgrade XCode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need xcode 4.2+ - basically get the latest one on the app store. in theory, you shouldn't have many problems (if any), but there are some subtle changes which can catch you out.

off the top of my head:

- modal view controllers don't seem to set `parentViewController` - instead you can use `presentingViewController` e.g. `[[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`
- viewWillAppear/viewDidApear/viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear notifications have changed in that in the past you didn't get them if you manually added views etc, but now you do. there's a good blog post on it here: http://gamesfromwithin.com/view-controller-notification-changes-on-ios5
- the only other thing that i can think of that i ran into was the location where xcode stores "Derived Data", but that was only an issue going from xcode3 -> xcode4 (and we were an edge case), so you shouldn't need to worry about that.